# div overflow and z-index

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

**Please have a look at the following fiddle:**

**https://jsfiddle.net/y7w705wb/20/**

```css
.row {
    height: 25px;
     width: 300px;
     background-color: red;
     overflow: visible;
     border: 1px solid black;
     position: absolute;
}
 .modal {
    width: 200px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: yellow;
     z-index: 10;
     position: absolute;
     left: 3px;
     top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
        Content
        <div class="modal"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="transform: translateY(25px);">
        Content
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The second div row overlaps the yellow "modal popup" I created in the first row. I am trying to let the yellow box overlap the second row. How can I archive that?
My prerequisites are, that I have a bunch of rows, but in some of them I want to display a small popup window, that contains information. 
This information should not be overlapped by subsequent rows.

**This is only a very basic example to show my core problem.
Any ideas?**

> Update:

**I updated my fiddle:**

**https://jsfiddle.net/y7w705wb/20/**

`The reason why I ask this question is, because I am using ag-grid as datatable in my app and want to display a modal inside one of the cells.
I cannot change the cell structure, so I really have to do it like in my fiddle example.`

Comment: Remove `z-index: 1;` from `.row` …?

Comment: The best idea from the usability or ergonomy point of view is to use a modal window to reach this job, instead on overlaping divs over another...

Comment: Yeah I know... but in this case I am using ag-grid... so I have no other choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove z-index: 1 from the .row class. It should work Fine.

Comment: That was almost it!

Comment: I changed my fiddle. The problem is still there if I use position: absolute.

Comment: why have you made row absolute?

Comment: Change .row to relative and add z-index: 0 to .row class and on hover change the z-index of target .row class to 1.Here`s the link -  https://jsfiddle.net/0fz2w4ub/1/

Comment: Perfect! :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove z-index for .row class

```
.row {
  height: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.modal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
}


<div class="row">
  Content
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  Content
</div>
```

OR 
You can try this also where z-index remains the same.

```
.row {
      height: 25px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: red;
      overflow: visible;
      z-index:1;
      border: 1px solid black;
      position: relative;
    }

    .modal {
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: yellow;
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
      left: 3px;
      top: 3px;
    }

<div class="row">
  Content
</div>
<div class="row">
  Content
</div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

OR you also have another solution for this issue:

.row div is a parent div so give it position relative and z-index for 1st div

```
.row {
 height: 25px; 
 width: 300px;
 background-color: red;
 position:relative;
 overflow: visible;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.modal {
 width: 200px; 
 height: 100px;
 background-color: yellow;
 z-index: 10;
 position: absolute;
 left: 3px;
 top: 3px;
} 

<div class="row" style="transform: translateY(0px);z-index:1"> 
   Content 
   <div class="modal"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" style="transform: translateY(25px);"> Content 
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah - I almost have the solution. I updated my fiddle without the z-index, but now with position: absolute.

Comment: .row div is a parent div so give it  position relative and z-index for 1st div <html>
<head>
<style>
.row {height: 25px; width: 300px; background-color: red; position:relative;overflow: visible; border: 1px solid black;  }
.modal {width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow; z-index: 10; position: absolute; left: 3px; top: 3px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row" style="transform: translateY(0px);z-index:1">
  Content
  <div class="modal"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row" style="transform: translateY(25px);">
  Content
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

HTML snippet:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="modal"></div>

    <div class="row">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS snippet:

```
    .row {height: 25px; width: 300px; background-color: red; overflow: visible; border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;}
    .modal {width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: yellow; z-index: 10; position: absolute; left: 3px; top: 3px; }
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/74kmte2g/5/

Comment: No, I definetly need my modal div inside the row-div. This is, because I am using ag-grid as datatable and I want to display a modal inside the rows.

Comment: I would say that it is a cleaner practice to put the modal out of the row itself, but you may also add a class to any row that has an active modal window (using javascript at runtime,i mean)  and set a different overflow property for that .row-modal-active class. Dirty, i guess, but it may work :)

Answer (score 0):

A modal window is normally above the normal document flow. Therefor I wouldn't put it inside an other element.

Taking it outside `.row` fixes the problem as well.

```css
.row {
  height: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.modal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  Content
</div>
<div class="row">
  Content
</div>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

I just switch `modal & second .row`.

**Here is the working code**

```css
.row {
    height: 25px;
     width: 300px;
     background-color: red;
     overflow: visible;
     border: 1px solid black;
     position: absolute;
}
 .modal {
    width: 200px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: yellow;
     z-index: 10;
     position: absolute;
     left: 3px;
     top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="row" style="transform: translateY(0px);">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="transform: translateY(25px);">
        Content
    </div>
    <div class="modal"></div>
</body>

</html>
```